# Pass selected value from EnumDropDownListFor to Controller - MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, enums, selectlist, dropdownlistfor

How can I pass the selected value from a @Html.EnumDropDownListFor to my controller? 
And actually I don't really want to pass the selected value as a string, but i want to pass coresponding number in the enum class from the selected item.

I've commented my code in the classes (Controller and View) below.

Enum

```
    public enum Leerjaar
{
    [Display(Name="Eerste leerjaar")]
    eerste = 1,
    [Display(Name = "Tweede leerjaar")]
    tweede = 2,
    [Display(Name = "Derde leerjaar")]
    derde = 3,
    [Display(Name = "Vierde leerjaar")]
    vierde = 4,
    [Display(Name = "Vijfde leerjaar")]
    vijfde = 5,
    [Display(Name = "Zesde leerjaar")]
    zesde = 6
}
```

ViewModel

```
      public class GraadIndexViewModel
{
    public Leerjaar leerjaar { get; set; }
    public GraadIndexViewModel(Leerjaar leerjaar){
        this.leerjaar = leerjaar;
    }
}
```

Controller

```
    public class GraadController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        //Passing the Enum to my ViewModel
        return View(new GraadIndexViewModel(new Leerjaar()));
    }

    [HttpPost]
    //And here I want to receive the selected value from the enumdropdown
    //in order to set my 'Leerjaar' field. 
    public ActionResult Index(GraadIndexViewModel g)
    {
        Leerjaar leerjaar = ???

    }
}
```

View

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm()) 
    {
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Kies uw leerjaar</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    @*Should I add something like new {leerjaarID = ???} here ?*@
    @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.leerjaar, "Kies uw leerjaar")

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Ga verder" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Remove the constructor from your ViewModel class.

Answer (score 2):

When you use the `html.SomethingFor( m => m.Property )` helpers, the field is bound to that model's property and is set by the model binder when ASP.NET MVC handles a POST submission:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(GraadIndexViewModel g)
{
    Leerjaar leerjaar = g.leerjaar;
}
```

To get the numeric value of an enum value, simply cast to `int` (or whatever the backing-type of the enum is):

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(GraadIndexViewModel g)
{
    Int32 leerjaarInt = (Int32)g.leerjaar;
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks and how can I get the number I gave to each value in my enum class?
Because I can't find something like:
int nr = g.leerjaar.getNumber()

Comment: @user3609750 I have revised my answer